# In tkinter how do I generate a new row every time a button is pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I've written  this code which makes one entry box appear on a new row when the button is pressed, but I'm not sure how to get it to make a new entry on a new row underneath the last one. My main problems are how to increment a row_number variable within the function without re-setting it every time the function is called, and how to make the function give a new name to the "new_entry" object each time it is called so that it doesn't overwrite itself.

```
def new_row():
    #Create widgets   
    new_entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=7)

    #Put widgets in grid
    new_entry.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

root = Tk()
createRow_button = ttk.Button(root, text='New Row', command=new_row)
createRow_button.grid()

root.mainloop
```

This is the first time I've asked a question on Stack Overflow so sorry if I've got anything wrong.

Comment: You should consider using `ttk.Treeview` rather than creating a bunch of `Entry` widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class and store the number of rows as class attribute, `self.num_rows`:

```
import Tkinter as tk


class App(object):
    def new_row(self):
        # Create widgets
        new_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=7)

        # Put widgets in grid
        self.num_rows += 1
        new_entry.grid(column=0, row=self.num_rows, sticky='WE')

    def __init__(self):
        self.num_rows = 1
        createRow_button = tk.Button(
            root, text='New Row', command=self.new_row)
        createRow_button.grid()

root = tk.Tk()
app = App()
root.mainloop()
```